# Save the input state with shinydataFilter

Tags: r, shiny

*I have a complex app, here I have tried to break it down to bare minimum to demonstrate the issue that I am facing.*

I am using [`shinyDataFilter`](https://github.com/dgkf/shinyDataFilter) to filter a dataframe. However, I have a list of dataframes as input and for each dataframe I have one filter associated with it.

```
library(shiny)
# devtools::install_github("dgkf/shinyDataFilter")
library(shinyDataFilter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Filter Data Example"),
  selectInput("dataset", "Select Dataset : ", c("df1", "df2")),
  uiOutput("data_filter"),
  dataTableOutput("table1"),
  dataTableOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  list_data <- list(df1 = data.frame(col1 = factor(letters[1:5]), col2 = 1:5), 
      df2 = data.frame(col1 = factor(letters[3:18]), col2 = 3:18, col3 = 1:16))
  
rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    rv$rv_child <- purrr::imap(list_data, function(x, y) 
                callModule(shiny_data_filter,paste0("data_filter_",y), data = x))
  })
  
  output$data_filter <- renderUI({
    req(input$dataset)
    nm <- paste0("data_filter_",input$dataset)
    shiny_data_filter_ui(nm)
  }) 
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    req(rv$rv_child)
    rv$rv_child$df1()
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    req(rv$rv_child)
    rv$rv_child$df2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

To reproduce the issue run the below code and by default first dataframe is selected in the dropdown. Select `col1` after clicking on "Add Filter" button and select few values. Select `df2` in dropdown and come back to `df1` again. Now see that the table1 is already filtered with the values selected earlier however, the input is lost which is confusing for the users. My goal is to display the filter inputs corresponding to the filtered table so they are consistent. When the user is back on `df1` they see the inputs that they had earlier selected.

[image]

Comment: The filters are not showing up for me.  Can you show the output of `sessionInfo()`? My environment might be different from yours

Comment: I think the issue is that you are overwriting the filters every time. A solution to that would be to place the filters into a `tabsetPanel` with hidden tabs, and then show the required filter/tab using an `observeEvent` bound to `input$dataset`. I can probably show it if I get the app working properly as in your GIF.

Comment: @LeonSamson I think the issue is with latest `shiny` package 1.8.0. I am using 1.7.5 and it works ok with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? It keeps all filters available and just hides them when requested when clicking on an item in the drop-down menu. The filters should now not change when selecting a different data frame.

Note: the filters do not show up in my environment after running your example. There might also be some package version dependency issues here.

```
library(shiny)
# devtools::install_github("dgkf/shinyDataFilter")
library(shinyDataFilter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Filter Data Example"),
  selectInput("dataset", "Select Dataset : ", c("df1", "df2")),
  tabsetPanel(id = "data_filters", type = "hidden"),
  dataTableOutput("table1"),
  dataTableOutput("table2")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  list_data <- list(df1 = data.frame(col1 = factor(letters[1:5]), col2 = 1:5), 
                    df2 = data.frame(col1 = factor(letters[3:18]), col2 = 3:18, col3 = 1:16))
  
  lapply(names(list_data), \(i){
    insertTab(
      inputId = "data_filters",
      tabPanel(
        title = i,
        shiny_data_filter_ui(paste0("data_filter_", i))
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$dataset, {
    updateTabsetPanel(
      inputId = "data_filters", 
      selected = input$dataset
      )
  })
  
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    rv$rv_child <- purrr::imap(list_data, function(x, y) 
      callModule(shiny_data_filter,paste0("data_filter_",y), data = x))
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    req(rv$rv_child)
    rv$rv_child$df1()
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    req(rv$rv_child)
    rv$rv_child$df2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note 2: if it would be okay to only show the data frame and the filter of the selected data frame (the one in `input$dataset`), I think it is better to create a UI and server module for one filter and table combination, and then loop over this for every desired data frame. But I guess that is not what you want in this case, is that correct?

Comment: I think your solution works very well. Thank you for helping even when the example was not working for you. Appreciate it!